# Why is the method createCalendarTimer(ScheduleExpression) undefined for the type TimerService?

Tags: java, maven

I am using this dependency in POM.XML:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

But when I try to invoke createCalendarTimer(ScheduleExpression) in javax.ejb.TimerService, I get:

"The method createCalendarTimer(ScheduleExpression, TimerConfig) is undefined for the type TimerService"

Thank you in advance for your help and attention!!

Regards.

Comment: With `<scope>provided</scope>` [you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope). Is the library in your container and is it configured properly so that it does?

Comment: I tried <scope>imported</scope> too. The library is in my container. I think the problem is that createCalendarTimer method is not available in Jboss EJB API 3.1. So I added maven dependency to  EJB API 3.0. And now the method is available. I wonder if I am going to face any issues by importing both EJB API versions.

Comment: Wich version of [jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec%22) do you use? I looked into the source of the latest _1.0.2.Final_ and the interface `TimerService` there contains: `Line 30: Timer createCalendarTimer(ScheduleExpression schedule)`, `Line 46: Timer createCalendarTimer(ScheduleExpression schedule, TimerConfig timerConfig)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated some dependencies in my project:

```
jboss-javaee-web-6.02.0.0.Final‌​
```

to

```
org.jboss.specjboss-javaee-7.0<‌​version>1.0.1.Final
```

. I have also changed dependency

```
org.jboss.spec.javax.ejbjboss-ejb-api_3.1_sp‌​ec
```

to

```
jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec
```

Now the method

```
createCalendarTimer(ScheduleExpression
```

is available